# Passing a country code as command line argument input

Tags: python, pycharm, command-line-arguments

I have a program that gets the code of a country with `raw_input()` and then send an email based on it.

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd

import pymysql

import sys

data=pd.read_CVS("filename")

country=raw_input("country name : ")

print("country name is :",sys.argv[1])

for index in data['emailid']:

    mail= index.split('@')[1]
    if(country == 'US'):
        if (mail=='yahoo.com'):
            print index
    elif(country == 'UK'):
        if(mail=='yahoo.com' or mail=='yahoo.co.uk'):
            print index
```

I want to change it to send the country code as command line argument input.

Example:

```
python programname.py 'UK'
```

and the related email ids as output.

Comment: now i want to give the command in the command line argument like

Comment: What is your actual question? What is failing, and how?

Comment: i want to send the input that is country name while executing the program like if i want all mails relater to 'UK' i have to give the input while executing...python program_name.py 'UK'

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` reads from standard input whereas `sys.argv` is the list of command line arguments. So if you want to use command line to pass in the country code, just delete the line containing `raw_input` and let `country` be `sys.argv[1]`.

Comment: if i delete the line rawinput then getting a name error

Comment: So sorry I didn't read the next few lines carefully. You actually only printed the command line argument but didn't assign it to the `country` variable you used later.

Answer (score 0):

you should try [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module,

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Example with non-optional arguments')    
parser.add_argument('country')  
args = parser.parse_args()
country = args.country
```

Comment: NameError: name 'country' is not defined                                                           
 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Example with non-optional arguments')
parser.add_argument('country')
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.country


for index in data['emailid']:
    mail= index.split('@')[1]
    if(country == 'US'):
        if (mail=='yahoo.com'):
            print index
    elif(country == 'UK'):
        if(mail=='yahoo.com' or mail=='yahoo.co.uk'):
            print index

Comment: Thankx Akshat i am not getting the nameerror, but i am getting all the records irrespective of the condition  for country .

Comment: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Example with non-optional arguments')
parser.add_argument('country')
args = parser.parse_args()
country=args.country
fo = open("outfile1.txt","wb+")
for index in profileid_supress['emailid']:
    mail= index.split('@')[1]
    if(country == 'US'):
        if (mail=='rocketmail.com'):
            fo.write(index + '\n')
    elif(country == 'UK'):
        if(mail=='yahoo.com' or mail=='yahoo.co.uk'):
            fo.write (index + '\n')

Comment: its difficult to read the code in comments, can you update your latest code in the question.